# Comparison between pointer and integer error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
for(NSInteger i = 0; i<[_tempPostalCodeList count]; i++){
            ***if(individualInfo.postalCode == [[_tempPostalCodeList objectAtIndex:i] postalCode])***{
                myAnnotation.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i Records!", [[_postalCount objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
            }
    }
```

I Do not know what is wrong with this piece of code. That line has a error.
 This works for Java but not for objective c. =( Someone plz help

Comment: what is the type of `postalCode`? What is the full error?

Comment: You really need to post more info about the different types you are using so that effective help can be provided.  A wild guess would be that individualInfo.postalCode is a primitive type (like int) and that postalCode is an NSNumber

Comment: if postal code is any kind of object, you may be trying to use isEqual: ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the lack of a lot of information in the question, my psychic powers tell me that the problem is that the message `-objectAtIndex:` of the `NSArray` class returns a generic object of type `id`.  So, the expression `[[_tempPostalCodeList objectAtIndex:i] postalCode]` is sending the `postalCode` message to an object of type `id`.  Since the compiler doesn't know the underlying type of the actual object, it can't deduce the return type of the `postalCode` message, so it assumes that it also returns `id`.

`id` is a pointer type, and since `postalCode` is an integral type, the compiler thinks you're trying to compare a pointer with an integer when it evaluates the `==` operator, hence the warning.  The way to fix this is to either insert a cast, or introduce a temporary variable:

```
// Option #1: Use a cast
if(individualInfo.postalCode ==
    [(MyClass*)[_tempPostalCodeList objectAtIndex:i] postalCode]) {
    ...
}

// Option #2: Use a temporary variable
MyClass *obj = [_tempPostalCodeList objectAtIndex:i];
if(individualInfo.postalCode == obj.postalCode) {
    ...
}
```

The reason that you can use a temporary variable without a cast is because the `id` type (returned by `-objectAtIndex:`) can be implicitly cast to any Objective-C class type by simple assignment (similar to how in C (but not C++), the `void*` type can be implicitly cast to any pointer type).